# Nginx port_in_redirect not working?

Tags: nginx, varnish

I recently set up a Nginx server to host a wordpress install and am using Varnish as a reverse proxy in front of the server. Varnish is running on port 80, so I have set up Nginx to listen to 80 and redirect. Unfortunately on redirection, the port 8080 is appended to the nginx request.

Including `port_in_redirect off` seems to be the general solution to this problem, but it doesn't appear to be working for me. I've attached the `/sites-enabled/default` config below. Am I doing anything wrong?! The php redirections seems to work fine, it's only at `location /`where it fails.

`/sites-enabled/default`:

```
server { 
    listen 8080 default;
    server_name "" xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;  #just using IP here (no domain yet)

    port_in_redirect off;
    server_name_in_redirect off;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;


    location / {
            root   /var/www/site/html/;
            index  index index.php;
            try_files $uri/ $uri /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(.*)$;
            fastcgi_pass   backend;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/site/html/$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING     $query_string;
            fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD   $request_method;
            fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE     $content_type;
            fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH   $content_length;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
            fastcgi_ignore_client_abort     off;
            fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
            fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
            fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
            fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
            fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT 80;
    }

    location ~ /.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
    location ~ /.git {
        deny  all;
    }
    location ~ /.svn {
        deny  all;
    }

}

upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

`nginx.conf`:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    multi_accept on; 
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     off;

    keepalive_timeout  30;
    tcp_nodelay        on;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

nginx: nginx version: nginx/1.0.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, just sorted it. Simple error - in the Wordpress admin site `wp-admin > Settings > WordPress address (URL)` and `Site address (URL)` both had the port 8080 in the URL! Hence the redirection. The above setup works fine like this.

If that doesn't solve your problem a one tip I learned was to add `print_r($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]);` in your index.php to ensure you are getting the correct port (80 in my case) set from fastcgi.

Hopefully this simple step can save someone some time!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to have your Nginx server block listen on your localhost IP, either 127.0.0.1 or [::1] (if you have IPv6 -- picks up IPv4, too) on either port 80 or 8080, then have Varnish listen to the outside world on your external IP, xx.xx.xx.xx or [::], on the same port you used for the Nginx server block. Then you don't have to redirect or defer or anything.